# In ASP core 1.0, when working with Localization, do I need to create a dummy class?

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I'm having trouble getting the Localization working, I'm learning using https://www.dropbox.com/s/e11jrxp1qlgyj56/locDoc.docx?dl=0 which is a draft for the official documentation. I can't tell if the problem I'm encountering is the VS ResX problem, or that I've missed something.

There are a lot of references to the dummy file when you look up Localization examples, but these are mostly out of date. They create the resx but then have a dummy class of the same name.

So my question is do I need the dummy file if I use the below logic (note that the resx DOES NOT have a .cs designer behind it).

```
public class RetailerController
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<RetailerController> _localizer;
    public RetailerController(IStringLocalizer<RetailerController> localizer)    
    {
        _localizer = localizer;    
    }
    public string Test() 
    {    
        return _localizer["Test"];
    }
}
```

I've set up the resource path to be a directory called Resource, this is the Resource Directory:

```
/Resource
    /Controllers
        RetailerController.en-GB.resx
```

At the moment, it just returns "Test" as opposed to the "Test SUCCESS" which is found in the resx.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you test your project by running it from the command line and tell us if the problem persists?

Comment: Could you type "set DNX_TRACE=1" in your CMD and then run it again and show us the screenshot with the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, are you running the project from Visual Studio? Because there is an important note in the document:

"Currently, resource files are not read when the project is run from Visual Studio. See this issue for more information. Until the issue with Visual Studio is addressed, you can test the project by running it from the 
command line."

So yeah VS ResX problem i would say.

Comment: I'm having trouble publishing to be able to test it using cmd. And trying the 'web' command instead of IIS Express from VS doesn't work (I believe it's because I've had to explicitly remove dnx 5 due to backwards compatibility with an old library.